# Why wouldn't this code work?

Tags: c

I dont understand why this wouldn't work. Thanks!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    extern int i;
    int i=20;
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

Compilation results in the following error:

```
main.c: In function 'main':  
main.c:6:9: error: declaration of 'i' with no linkage follows extern declaration  
main.c:5:16: note: previous declaration of 'i' was here
```

Note: Code compiled online at [CompileOnline](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php)

Comment: *How* doesn't it work? You get compilation errors? Linker errors? Runtime errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int i;
```

Here variable i is declared and memory is allocated for it but not initialized.

```
extern int i;
```

Whenever extern is used, the variable is just declared and memory will not be allocated for it. In order to access it you have to redeclare same variable externally.
Here extern refers to that, you will be defining the value of that variable(i) outside the program(external source). In your case, you do it inside so it will not work as you expected. It can be either defined outside main program or by external programs.

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   extern int i; //Declared but memory not allocated
   printf("%d",i);
 return 0;
 }
int i=20; //Allocated memory for i and initialized to 20 outside the prog
```

Output:

```
20
```

Global extern variables can also be initialized directly, where as local extern variables cannot be.

```
#include<stdio.h>
extern int i=10; //Declared, Memory allocated and defined.
int main()
{
    extern int j; //Declared but memory not allocated
    printf("%d --> %d",i,j);
return 0;
}
int j=20; //Memory Allocated and value defined externally.
```

Output:

```
10 --> 20
```

You can also refer to this [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/) to know more about it.

Answer (score 8):

This won't work since you're trying to use `i` in two very different ways in the same scope.

The name `i` can't refer to *both*  some `extern` data that someone else is defining, *and*  a local variable.

If you just want to assign to the external variable, don't re-declare it:

```
extern int i;

i = 20;
```

Comment: But where is the storage allocated for `i` because it is defined nowhere in the program outside `main`. Doesn't linker complain about that?

Comment: The storage for i is allocated in an external source file which we have to include in our program.

Answer (score 3):

You are mistakenly re declaring `i`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    extern int i;
    i=20;     //Simply assign the value here. why redeclare with `int`
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You've already declared `i` as an `int` in

```
extern int i;
```

And then you go ahead and declare it again with

```
int i=20;
```

Try doing this instead

```
extern int i;
i=20;
```

Answer (score 1):

you have declared `i` twice which resulted in redefinition error

Answer (score 0):

`extern` indicates to the compiler that somewhere outside there exists a variable called `i` which is of type `int`.

Here, `outside` could be in the same program or in some other `translation`(another `.c` file) unit.

But you're redeclaring the same `i` which you already declared.

Also, if you're only executing the following program(without linking other files `.c`) it wont work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
  extern int i;
  i=20;     
  printf("%d",i);
}
```

It gives a linker error complaining that `i` is unresolved because the linker was unable to find the definition for `i` and no storage was allocated to it as it is not defined outside the main.